# Python manually create jwt token without library

Tags: python, jwt

I want to generate jwt token manually without any library in python. I searched detailed information or tutorial for this but I couldn't. All information about jwt in python is library included. Is there any resource that I can benefit to generate jwt token in python?

Comment: your post is quite confusing. *I want to import jwt in project it says jwt is not accessed* - that just means that you're importing something that you don't use.  - *don't want to use any library* - but why do you import it when you don't want to use it? Manually creating and verifiying tokens is not diffcult, depending on the level of doing things manually. Are libs for base64 encoding and hashing ok? On https://jwt.io/introduction it 's explained what you need to do. You can of course break it down further, manually base64 encoding and decoding, manually creating a hmac and so on.

Comment: I am beginner. I thought jwt is an default integrated then realized it is not. I am searching for tutorial or more detailed information in python for those steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A senior colleague taught this to me. There is no need huge libraries if you want to make a simple one.

```
def base64url_decode(input):
    
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input)
def base64url_encode(input):
    stringAsBytes = input.encode('ascii')
    stringAsBase64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(stringAsBytes).decode('utf-8').replace('=','')
    return stringAsBase64 


def jwt_creator(expiration, userid, userrole):
    header = {
        "alg": "HS256",
        "typ": "JWT"
    }
    payload = {'expired': expiration,
               'userid': userid,
               'userrole': userrole
               }
    secret_key = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)    
    total_params = str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(header))) + '.' + str(base64url_encode(json.dumps(payload)))
    signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode(), total_params.encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    token = total_params + '.' + str(base64url_encode(signature))
    return token
```

Comment: The senior colleague has forgotten to explain you, that [the base64 output padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_padding) can be "", "=" or "==", depending on the string length and JWT do not have paddings. However, when using `urlsafe_b64decode()` you can drop the padding completely i.e. just call `return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(input)`

Comment: @AlexanderFarber that's right. updated.

Answer (score 9):

I came across this SO thread because I wanted to create a JWT for Zoom without using the JWT library. As recommended by darth baba, I went through the PyJWT source code to recreate the implementation by using the default libraries. Hopefully, this helps some others in the future:

```
import base64
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

api_key = 'XXXXXX'
api_sec = 'XXXXXX'

due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
expiry = int(due_date.timestamp())

def base64url_encode(input: bytes):
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(input).decode('utf-8').replace('=','') 

def jwt(api_key, expiry, api_sec):
    
    segments = []
    
    header = {"typ": "JWT", "alg": "HS256"}
    payload = {"iss": api_key, "exp": expiry}
    
    json_header = json.dumps(header, separators=(",",":")).encode()
    json_payload = json.dumps(payload, separators=(",",":")).encode()
    
    segments.append(base64url_encode(json_header))
    segments.append(base64url_encode(json_payload))
    
    signing_input = ".".join(segments).encode()
    key = api_sec.encode()
    signature = hmac.new(key, signing_input, hashlib.sha256).digest()

    segments.append(base64url_encode(signature))
                    
    encoded_string = ".".join(segments)

    return encoded_string
```